emscripten module usage and multiple instance?
emscripten 1.38.31
I compiled C++ to a pure JS file with the following command line:
call emcc -fno-exceptions -s ASSERTIONS=1 --closure 1 -s MODULARIZE=1 --memory-init-file 0 -s WASM=0 -g0 -v -s EXPORT_NAME='NigrumObject' --bind -std=c++11 -Oz -o nigrum_lib.html all_cpp_file_list...


The INITIAL_MEMORY is set to 16M by default, and it's the minimum value. Does this mean it will use 16M of memory?
Then I got a nigrum_lib.js file.
I use the following JavaScript code in my HTML file:
let arr = [];
for ( let i = 0; i < 10; i ++ ){
    const obj = NigrumObject();//EXPORT_NAME='NigrumObject'
    arr.push(obj);
}
//call function of obj of arr.


does this mean it will use 16M * 10 memory?
The NigrumObject is used in my game server (Node.js). It's a fighting game, with 6 players in a room, and each room corresponds to a NigrumObject. It's very memory-intensive, i have 2000 players in a 8 core 16GB server.
Are there any ways to optimize memory usage?
NigrumObject contain algorithms and game data, may be can not be share with other rooms.
Are there any ways to optimize memory usage?
